# Getting IPv4 and IPv6 programatically of Android Device with non deprecated methods, both when on Wifi and when on Carier's network

Tags: android, ipv6, android-networking, ipv4

I came across a few discussion about getting **IPv4 and IPv6 addresses programmatically on Android**. The problem with these other questions and answers is:

- Those question/answers are **fairly old by now thus often deprecated**. I am looking for a way to get it done in a **non-deprecated** way (for example, InetAddressUtils is deprecated and so are others).
- I want to know how to get **both a IPv4 and IPv6** address when **on Wifi or on the Carrier's** network.

Is there someone who could tell me how to get it done in a **short** and **neat** way without a lengthy method (if that is possible)?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html

Comment: Thank you, I've checked it before, but that page was back then not of a great help

Answer (score 5):

For ipv4,ipv6  You can use

```
   public String getIpv4() {
            try {
                for (Enumeration<NetworkInterface> en = NetworkInterface
                        .getNetworkInterfaces(); en.hasMoreElements(); ) {
                    NetworkInterface intf = en.nextElement();
                    for (Enumeration<InetAddress> enumIpAddr = intf
                            .getInetAddresses(); enumIpAddr.hasMoreElements(); ) {
                        InetAddress inetAddress = enumIpAddr.nextElement();
                        System.out.println("ip1--:" + inetAddress);
                        System.out.println("ip2--:" + inetAddress.getHostAddress());

                        if (!inetAddress.isLoopbackAddress() && inetAddress instanceof Inet4Address) {
                            String ipaddress = inetAddress.getHostAddress().toString();
                            return ipaddress;
                        }


                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Log.e("IP Address", ex.toString());
            }
            return null;
        }

//ipv6
  public String getLocalIpV6() {
        try {
            for (Enumeration<NetworkInterface> en = NetworkInterface
                    .getNetworkInterfaces(); en.hasMoreElements(); ) {
                NetworkInterface intf = en.nextElement();
                for (Enumeration<InetAddress> enumIpAddr = intf
                        .getInetAddresses(); enumIpAddr.hasMoreElements(); ) {
                    InetAddress inetAddress = enumIpAddr.nextElement();
                    System.out.println("ip1--:" + inetAddress);
                    System.out.println("ip2--:" + inetAddress.getHostAddress());

                    if (!inetAddress.isLoopbackAddress() && inetAddress instanceof Inet6Address) {
                        String ipaddress = inetAddress.getHostAddress().toString();
                        return ipaddress;
                    }


                }
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.e("IP Address", ex.toString());
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Yes, this code propably gives IPv6-address, that works in localhost. meaning in phone itself, but that kind IPv6-address is useless. I haven't found logic how to choose one working IPv6 address, meaning an IPv6 address that you can ping from other device from internet, This is found in phones Settings-app by UI. Best choices are those which interfaceAddress.networkPrefixLength in high. IPv6 addresses can be network address or devices single address

Comment: Reijo, are you getting ipv6 addresses from an emulator and seeing if they work from the outside?  Those addresses won't work from the outside.  You can "ping6" some of those IPv6 addresses using an "adb shell" command. That's because those ipv6 addresses have a site scope.  What I've noticed is that in an emulated environment, the active network interface gets 3 additional ipv6 link addresses added and some of those aren't pingable.  For security reasons, the android emulator runs on an isolated network and has its own dhcp and dns servers. Are you using global scope IPv6 addresses?

Comment: The problem with the getLocalIpV6 method, is that it arbitrarily grabs the first IPv6 address it finds from any Network interface.  Most likely you want to get the IpV6 address from the active network.  And to make matters more complicated, (if you read my previous comment), in an emulated environment the active Network interface gets 3 additionally IPv6 addresses added.  So which one should you choose?  I'm trying to find any answer to that problem.  Anybody know?